# How to calculate column mean of a matrix of dimension ( i , n) where n (> 1) is a fixed integer and i = 1,2,3,...n?

Tags: r

How to calculate column mean of a matrix of `dimension ( i , n)`  where `n (> 1)` is a fixed integer and `i = 1,2,3,...n`  in R? I have already used the code `colMeans(x[1:i, ])` inside for loop where `x` is a matrix. It shows the error:

> 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions

Comment: `x[1, ]` is not a matrix. Use `x[1,, drop = FALSE]` to prevent it from dropping dimensions.

Comment: Here I am talking about x[1:i, ] which is a matrix.

Comment: Not when i = 1.  That is why you are getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

Use `drop=FALSE` as in the comment above. But you might find `dplyr::cummean()` useful. It is also a lot faster than your `for` loop solution.

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- data.frame(matrix(runif(20,20,40), ncol = 4))
sapply(dat, cummean)
```